# Como funciona o campo BLOB?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, firebird

Olá, diretamente perguntando, como funciona esse tipo de campo?

Sei que existe três tipos:

> BLOB = 64KB, MEDIUMBLOB = 16MB e LONGBLOB = 4GB

Dado esse exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPROMISSOS (
  ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
  DESCRICAO  BLOB,
  DATA_HORA  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

Mas como ele funciona na pratica, no banco de dados ele apresenta `Size 80`, o que é esse 80 e como ele expande?

Comment: É MySQL ou Firebird? Apresenta o tamanho onde? Tem algo específico que queira saber?

Comment: Então, no Firebird pelo IbExpert apresenta 80, no Mysql não posso ver pq só uso atualmente o phpmyadmin,especifico mesmo é como ele funciona, essa expansão dele eu não entendi. Esse 80 ai definitivamente não entendi.

Comment: Primeiramente, não é um "campo".. é um tipo de dado (data type). E a sua pergunta é vaga e confusa. O título pergunta uma coisa e no contexto e nos comentários vc pede outra coisa específica sobre o "Size 80" apresentado no client firebird. Defina o que vc quer primeiro e descreva de forma mais consistente na pergunta.

Comment: @DanielOmine A pergunta foi bem direta sobre o que eu queria saber, inclusive você não leu direito "o titulo é: Como funciona o campo BLOB?" e na primeira linha eu novamente perguntei: "Olá, diretamente perguntando, como funciona esse tipo de campo?" E sobre o Size 80 basta observar que adicionei as 2 Tags diretamente na pergunta (Mysql e Firebird). Se não tiver algo para ajudar como resposta, não precisa se preocupar, pois com as 2 Respostas postadas eu já consegui sanar muita duvida! Caso ainda insista que a pergunta é Vaga, basta sinalizar, temos Ótimos moderadores de plantão! Obrigado!!!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### O que é um campo blob?

O blob (Binary Large Object - grande objeto binário) é um campo criado para o armazenamento de qualquer tipo de informações em formato binário, dentro de uma tabela de um banco de dados.

O MySQL trabalha com campos blob, que são na verdade campos texto (TEXT) com uma única diferença: campos texto são"case-insensitive", ao contrário dos blob"s.

Os blob"s são divididos em quatro tipos (no MySQL), sendo que a diferença existente de um para o outro é unicamente a capacidade de armazenamento e trabalho do campo. Estes são:

**TINYBLOB** - campo blob de armazenamento máximo igual a 255 caracteres (8 bits) mais 1 de controle;

**BLOB** - o mesmo que o Tinyblob, porém armazenando até 16535 caracteres (16 bits) mais 2 de controle;

**MEDIUMBLOB** - o mesmo que o tinyblob, porém armazenando até 16777216 caracteres (24 bits) mais 3 de controle;

**LONGBLOB** - o mesmo que o tinyblob, porém armazenando até 4294967295 caracteres (32 bits) mais 4 de controle.

Além disto, existem as seguintes particularidades com os campos blobs:

1. Não podem ser chaves primárias (excluindo Tinyblob);
2. Não é possível usar os comandos GROUP e SORT com campos blob;
3. São reconhecidos como um LONGVARCHAR para drivers ODBC.

### Segment Size

O segment size (tamanho do segmento) é definido para aumentar o desempenho de entrada e saída dos dados no blob.

Ele deve variar conforme o tipo de informação que se deseja guardar.

**Para memos curtos** - mesmo que em alguns casos se estenda um pouco mais pode-se definir o tamanho como 100 bytes, que informa que devem ser processados blocos de 100 bytes de cada vez.

**Para vídeos ou gráficos grandes** -  deve ser informado um comprimento maior. o comprimento máximo é de 65536 bytes (64 Kb), isto porque todos os índices do blob são armazenados e lidos em bloco.

Quando um blob é lido, o seu conteúdo é extraído em blocos por isso, quanto maior o bloco, maior o número de bytes processados simultaneamente, aumentando a performance.

Anteriormente o valor padrão era de 80 bytes (porque cabiam 80 caracteres numa linha do monitor), mas para os computadores atuais esse valor pode ser maior. 2048 é um valor recomendado como padrão desde a versão 6 do Interbase.

Lembrando que o segment size não limita o tamanho do campo, mas sim como ele é manipulado.

Basicamente, no mysql você não precisa especificar o segment size por que ele consegue analisar o tamanho do blob na sua declaração e utilizar a paginação adequada, agora no Firebird é necessário, visto que existe apenas um tipo de blob.

**Para mudar a propriedade SEGMENT SIZE no Firebird é assim:**

```
UPDATE RDB$FIELDS set
RDB$SEGMENT_LENGTH = 1024
WHERE RDB$FIELD_NAME = 'RDB$85'
```

Lembrando que esta forma de atualizar a propriedade só funcionará até o Firebird 3 a partir desta versão o procedimento indicado a realizar é criar uma coluna temporária transferir todo o conteúdo,deletar o campo blob e cria-lo com o SEGMENT SIZE  apropriado, e depois mover os dados para a coluna recem criada.

Comment: Entendi, no Firebird como eu faço para aumentar o 80 para um valor maior ? Posso aumentar para qualquer valor até o limite ou existe tamanhos pré-definidos ?

Answer (score 5):

O blob (Binary Large Object - grande objeto binário) serve para armazenar qualquer tipo de dado, videos, imagens, sons, etc.

Esse 80 que você está vendo é o SEGMENT SIZE default usado na criação do campo.

SEGMENT SIZE define a quantidade de dados que vai entrar e sair no momento de leitura e gravação por vez, em casos de videos grandes, por exemplo, é indicado que ele seja maior, podendo chegar ao limite maximo de 65536 bytes (64 Kb)

É importante entender que o SEGMENT SIZE não define o tamanho do campo, mas sim como ele é manipulado.

Quando ao crescimento, internamente o banco de dados grava o valor da célula (linha x coluna) que está sendo inserida em blocos de 4k (se não me engano é esse valor) em um relacionamento 1:N (linha:blocos de blob).

Então o espaço ocupado pelo blob vai depender de quantos blocos o banco de dados precisa para guardar toda a informação.