# Como inserir/recuperar imagem no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi-xe8

Gostaria se saber de uma forma clara e simples como inserir/recuperar imagem no banco de dados MySQL?

Estou usando o FireDac para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados MySQL.

Eu tenho uma imagem JPEG e quero guardá-la em um banco de dados MySQL e poder restaurá-la quando necessário. Pelo que pude observar é algo o tipo de dados `blob`, mas não sei a forma correta de se fazer.

Comment: Quando você diz, "inserir/recuperar imagem do banco de dados" você quer dizer criar/restaurar ?

Comment: Sim, Exatamente, Inserir imagem, e consultar/restaurar a imagem do BD.

Comment: Viniam, Nesse vídeo mostra todo o processo, desde a captação pelo componente Image até a passagem de parâmetro pra STP, em Delphi 7, mas é pra SQL Server, porém, pode dar uma luz! Segue o link pro vídeo: https://youtu.be/8pGGDFG_Kis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após uma conexão feita com o `FireDac`, você pode usar um de seus próprios componentes para executar os comandos `SQLs`.

O Componente esta na mesma aba do `FireDacconnection`, trata-se do `FDQuery`.

**Gravando a imagem no Banco de Dados:**

```
procedure frmTeste.btnIncluirFotoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vArquivo: TFileStream;
begin
  vArquivo := TFileStream.Create('d:\01.bmp', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  //Pode ser feito Insert ou Update
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tbl_usuario (FOTO) VALUES(:FOTOCARREGADA)');
  FDQuery1.Params[0].DataType := ftBlob;
  FDQuery1.ParamByName('FOTOCARREGADA').AsStream := vArquivo;
  FDQuery1.ExecSQL;
  FDQuery1.Close;
end;
```

**Lendo a imagem do Banco de Dados:**

```
procedure frmTeste.btnCarregarFotoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vFoto   : TStream;
  vImagem : TBitmap;
begin     
  FDQuery1.Close;
  FDQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id_usuario = 6');
  FDQuery1.Open;

  //Lendo a imagem do campo BLOB para a Memória
  vFoto := FDQuery1.CreateBlobStream(FDQuery1.FieldByName('FOTO'), bmRead);

  //Criando a instância de TBitmap (pode ser JPG tb)
  vImagem := TBitmap.Create;

  //Carregando a imagem a partir do stream TStream
  vImagem.LoadFromStream(vFoto);

  //Exibindo a Imagem
  Image1.Picture.Assign(vImagem);
  //Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(vFoto); //Caso esteja usando FMX ao invés de VCL
end;
```

Para ter um sucesso na gravação e leitura dos dados, a escolha do tipo do campo **Blob** deve ser levado em consideração!

Segue uma pergunta que fiz aqui mesmo com boas respostas sobre o campo [BLOB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100802/como-funciona-o-campo-blob)

Comment: Não amigo, Eu quis dizer inserir imagem para o banco de dados mysql, Porque eu sei fazer utilizar o firedac, fazer inserção e consultas de boa, A minha dúvida é a inserção de Imagens no banco de dados, Inserir e trazer a imagem de volta, Compreendeu? Infelizmente já pesquisei em diversas linguas e até agora não vi algo que funcione corretamente.

Comment: Mesmo você explicando nesse comentário não entendi nada ainda, respondi achando que era algo referente a isso, vamos lá, Imagem, você esta se referindo a Bitmap? JPEG ?

Comment: Bom eu me refiro a imagem JPEG, Vou tentar ser mais claro desta vez: Bom Eu tenho uma imagem JPEG e quero guarda-la em um banco de dados mysql e poder restaura-la quando necessário. Pelo que pude observar é algo o tipo de dados blob, Mas não sei a forma correta de se fazer, Compreendeu?

Comment: Entendi, reformulando a Resposta, favor, adicionar essa informação à pergunta!

Comment: Já reformulei a pergunta :).

Comment: @Viniam vamos aos Testes, resposta editada!

Comment: Júnior Moreira, Muito Obrigado pela ajuda cara, Então eu testei aqui e consegui inserir a imagem ao banco de dados funcionou perfeitamente, Mas infelizmente não estou conseguindo fazer a recuperação da imagem(consulta) ... Obs estamos no Delphi xe8 Multi-Device: Image1.Picture.Assign(vImagem); , Não existe, Então mudei para: Image1.MultiResBitmap.Assign(vImagem); ... Está dando erro ao consultar o BD :(

Comment: @Viniam testa isso: `Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(vFoto);`

Comment: Funcinou perfeitamente, Já classifiquei a resposta como Resolvido, Meus parabéns e obrigado pela ajuda.