# Como salvar um arquivo PDF no banco de dados e disponibilizá-lo para download?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicaçao web utilizando o PlayFramework, e estou precisando um arquivo que será uma especie de guia (documentaçao) para os usuarios que utilizarão minha aplicaçao poderem baixarem ou visualizar pelo proprio navegador a fim de guiá-lo no manuseio da plataforma. Estou utilizando o banco de dados local por enquanto, o H2 para armazenar meus dados. Como salvo esse documento pdf no meu banco para poder disponibilizar depois para download ou visualiaçao?

Aqui esta uma das classes do banco, onde poderia ser inserido aqui mesmo o arquivo pdf.

```
@Entity
public class Auditoria extends Model{

public String usuario;
public String action;
public String controller;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date data;   

public Auditoria(){
    this.data = new Date();
}
}
```

Comment: Você já cogitou salvar o arquivo em um diretório e salvar no banco apenas o caminho do mesmo? É uma alternativa bem melhor.

Comment: nao, nao sabia dessa alternativa, pode me ajudar a implementar?

Comment: To indo pra casa, quando chegar lá monto uma resposta pra você.

Comment: @DiegoAugusto fico no aguardo

Comment: Você poderia salvar como blob em base64 no banco mas a proposta do @CarlosDiego de salvar o caminho de diretório do mesmo é bem melhor

Comment: Pode me ajudar a implementar isso @RômuloGabrielRodrigues?

Comment: Talvez apenas mais tarde pois no meu trabalho não tenho ambiente Java e não tenho experiência nesse framework Play que está sendo usado

Comment: OK, fico no aguardo @RômuloGabrielRodrigues

Comment: Exceto em casos muito específicos, evite salvar arquivos no banco de dados, tente fazer por referencias, seja diretório,link ou nome do arquivo, senão pode incorrer em problemas de desempenho na transferência dentre outros.
<br>Caso precise fazer mesmo o arquivamento binario segue:<br>
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100802/como-funciona-o-campo-blob <br>
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode salvar qualquer arquivo em um banco de dados sql utilizando uma coluna varbinary(max).

Só criar uma método que converta o arquivo para binário e salvar no DB, e depois para ler o mesmo é só fazer o inverso.

Comment: tem algum material ou trecho de codigo que pode me auxiliar nisso? Nao tenho experiencia nesse conteudo, estou aprendendo agora, portanto nao sei por onde começar.

Comment: tente seguir isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579373/saving-any-file-to-in-the-database-just-convert-it-to-a-byte-array

Comment: Olá @CarlosDiego. É realmente necessário implementar dessa forma? Se não for gostaria de sugerir que você crie uma entidade de abstração do arquivo e o salve em formato .pdf em algum diretório pré-definido, dessa forma você teria uma entidade que contém o arquivo e poderia acessá-lo sem problemas.

Comment: eh isso dai mesmo @luanlucas, essa maneira resolveria meu problema, tu pode me ajudar a implementar isso?

Comment: @CarlosDiego podemos tentar. Há alguma outra forma que podemos conversar?

Comment: pode ser pelo wpp?

Comment: @luanlucas ou entao tu pode criar uma sala aqui pra conversarmos?

Comment: @CarlosDiego, criei uma sala com o nome "Criar abstração de arquivo em banco de dados", entra lá pra vermos se conseguimos resolver isso. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71289/criar-abstracao-de-arquivo-em-banco-de-dados